# Imbalanced class with same rows?

Tags: python, data, class-imbalance

In my dataset i have 3 classes-> 0,1,2. 
0(72k),1(13k)and 2(13K) in brackets are there count.
So whenever i try to predict them with any algorithm ,i observed that almost all the "2"'s are predicted as "0".
On little exploration i found that there are some rows where attributes of 0 and 2 are exactly same.
Any technique to tackle this issue?

Comment: If you have identical rows with different classification, thais is the main problem, even before the imbalance. Either the classification is wrong or your features are too restricted and therefore cannot differ between the cases.

Comment: As DaL said, the same examples having different classes is indicative of a lack of information entropy in your feature-space. You need to re-evaluate your feature selection.

Comment: You say some rows and attributes, what does it mean? What's the percentage of the rows? How many attributes are identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The further exploration of your data would help. Are there, for example, some clusters where relative frequencies of your classes are much different from average?

Now I see two ways to increase sensitivity of your algorithm toward class 2:

1. Use probabilistic prediction. Maybe what you really need is to estimate the probability that the current example belongs to class 2. If identical observations are sometimes marked as 0 and sometimes as 2, you cannot do much better then say "with probability X this is the second class".
2. Use `class_weights` and increase them for class 2. This will lead to more predictions of 2 and less predictions of 0 and 1. With imbalansed datasets it sometimes helps.

Comment: i tried playing with weights but problem is whenever i put weight on 2 the overall accuracy decreases. 
And i absolutely agree on your point that little exploration is needed in order to find the features which are sensitive to class 2. I will work on it and let you know if an further doubts.
THanks for your time! :)

Comment: Overall accuracy would indeed  decrease if you mingle with weights. However, accuracy may be not what you want from your algorithm. With class imbalance, other metrics, such as class-wise precision, recall, F-metric, and ROC AUC are sometimes more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to do more exploration on data, so that you find some unique feature which helps us in understanding why that record has been classified into that particular cluster/segment(on training data).

You need to balance the data so that the model can understand and can predict accordingly.

As [@David](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/24162/david-dale) has mentioned above such situation can be played around by giving weight-age to the classes and so on.

Do let me know if you have any additional questions.